# Have to move variable from left to right in Javascript. Professor has up and down as sample

Tags: javascript, html

new to javascript and taking a college course for game programming. Only using notepad. Now I have to move an object, in this case just the letter "o" from left to right. My professor provides code for the object going up and down the screen so I tried just to switch the "top" with "left" but it still wont move.

Prof sample:

```
<!-- Microsoft Edge, IE10/11, FireFox, Chrome -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var bH = document.documentElement.clientHeight; // return the browser’s height
        function init() {
            var m1 = document.getElementById("m1"); // m1 represent m1
            var y = parseInt(m1.style.top); // y-coordinate of m1
            if (y >= bH) {
                y = 0;
            } else {
                y++;
            }
            m1.style.top = y + "px";
            s1 = setTimeout("init()", 10); // wait 10 milliseconds and then call init
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            init(); // onload event occurs right after a page is loaded
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="m1" style="position: absolute; top: 0px">o</span>
</body>
</html>
```

My attempt:

```
<!-- Chrome -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        var bW = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        function init() {
            var o = document.getElementById("o");
            var x = parseInt(o.style.left);
            if (x >= bW) {
                x = 0;
            } else {
                x++;
            }
            o.style.left = x + "px";
            s1 = setTimeout("init()", 10);
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            init();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="o" style="position: absolute; left: 0px">o</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove `;` in end of the `window.onload = function(); ` .

Comment: okay removed it

Answer (score 1):

Two three mistakes

1. using `;` after `window.onload = function();` is wrong
2. Don't add the function inside " " like `s1=setTimeout("init()", 10);` (it will work otherwise also, but i can't correctly figure out why not working in your case)

Solution: (**js part only**)

```
var bW = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

function init() {
  var o = document.getElementById("o");
  var x = parseInt(o.style.left);
  if (x >= bW){
    x = 0;
  }
  else{
    x++;
  }
  o.style.left = x + "px";
  s1=setTimeout(init(), 10);
}

window.onload = function(){
  init();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fixes on syntax, but yeah cant figure out why it wont work. Another guy commented with fix and I hit "run this code" button and it worked here haha,